# Why volatile worked for container like ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

`volatile` worked when a variable is reassigned. But why `volatile` worked when an `ArrayList` is changed like below?

```
package io.github.baijifeilong.thread;

import io.vavr.control.Try;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class VolatileApp3 {

    private static volatile List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).forEach($ -> {
            Try.run(() -> TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1));
            System.out.printf("Appending %d => ", $);
            list.add($);
            System.out.println(list);
        })).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (list.size() < 5) {
//                Try.run(() -> TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(0));
            }
            System.out.println("List size >= 5 now");
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The console result is:

```
Appending 1 => [1]
Appending 2 => [1, 2]
Appending 3 => [1, 2, 3]
Appending 4 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
Appending 5 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
List size >= 5 now
Appending 6 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Appending 7 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Appending 8 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Appending 9 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Appending 10 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Are you saying that the other thread doesn't see updates to `list` if it's not marked as `volatile`?

Comment: Lots of things can work in simple tests and not actually work in real concurrent situations.  Concurrency bugs are _never_ obvious, and it's always possible for tests to miss them.  This is all to say: making a `List` `volatile` doesn't actually solve anything, and it'll still be buggy code.

Comment: Actually I have observed that as well. As far as I know (I could be wrong), when the system reads a `volatile` variable, it updates the CPU cache of everything, not just the variable. This has something to do with ensuring "happens-before" rule.

Comment: Echoing what Louis Wasserman said: The Java Language guarantees that if you obey the rules, your program will work.  It does _not_ guarantee that your program will break if you don't obey the rules. An incorrect program might work today, but not after you upgrade your OS, or it might work on your computer, but not on somebody else's, etc. You can not find concurrency bugs by testing. (At least, not _yet_, anyway.) The only way to be sure of writing correct multi-threaded code is to understand, and scrupulously follow the rules.